# How second-order differential equations do not violate causality?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**I copy this question from physics stack exchang**e

The second order differential equations are time reversible. That means: they don't distinguish the time arrow direction. There is no reason for the time to flow forward.

My professor told me that there are two solutions to such equations, one of which describes processes going forward and one backward in time. The "backward" solution violates causality, so we say that only the "forward" solution is physical and the other simply don't exist.

Is this explanation correct? Has this anything to do with the fact we use imaginary numbers?

And one more question: How is causality not violated?

Comment: Here is the link from [physics.SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/323233/how-second-order-differential-equations-do-not-violate-causality)

Comment: This is a question about physics, not mathematics. The answer at the physics site where  @YujieZha found the question says it's really a question about philosophy as much as about physics. So you won't get any help here.

Comment: Indeed, this is completely off-topic here.

Comment: @EthanBolker I ask what is the difference between the two solutions It is a mathematics question

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I ask what is the difference between the two solutions It is a mathematics question

Comment: If you are asking a mathematical question, then it does not make a lot of sense. There is no such thing as «two solutions»: the set of solutions of a *linear* 2nd order differential equation is a $2$-dimensional vector space, and that space has many bases (if the equation is not linear, then it is even harder to make sense of what you are asking) It is quite unclear what two solutions you have in mind, and what exactly it means for a solution to violate casuality. We use imaginary numbers only if we use them, but we are not obliged to, so it is hard to know what that means, also.

Comment: The very best plan is, without any doubt, to ask your professor what he meant when he said that, as he surely knows.

Comment: As far as I know mathematics doesn't operate in terms of casuality or the time arrow. So this is not a mathematics question. There's no special place for the letter $t$ in mathematics